# When does $y^T (A^{-1})^T x = y^T (A^{-1}) x$ for invertible $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*Background*: Trying to do a Cauchy expansion. I want to show that for $M = \begin{bmatrix}k & x^T\\y & A\end{bmatrix}$, $det(M) = det(A) \cdot (k - y^T A^{-1} x)$ for invertible A. Note, M is a 2-by-2 block matrix.

So I take the transpose of M, giving:

$$det \begin{bmatrix}k & x^T\\y & A\end{bmatrix} = det \begin{bmatrix}k & y^T\\x & A^T\end{bmatrix}$$

Then using the Schur complement, I get $det \begin{bmatrix}k & y^T\\x & A^T\end{bmatrix} = det(A^T) \cdot det(k - y^T (A^T)^{-1} x) = det(A) \cdot (k - y^T (A^{-1})^T x)$.

Close, but not quite what I want.

> When $A$ is invertible, are there any rules relating $y^T (A^{-1})^T x$ and $y^T (A^{-1}) x$?

Answer (score 2):

The equation $y^{T}(A^{-1})^{T}x=y^{T}A^{-1}x$ holds for all $x$ and $y$ iff $(A^{-1})^{T}=A^{-1}$.

Comment: Just take $x=e_{i}, y=e_{j}$ for $i,j=1, \ldots, n$. Then its clear. Here $e_i$ is a coloumn vector with 1 on $i^{th}$ position and 0 everywhere elses.